# api cannot accept XML

Tags: xml-parsing, xmlhttprequest, asp.net-core-webapi, content-type

I'm using .netCore 3.1 and this is my first time dealing with XML.
I'm trying to read xml data, and parse them then save them to the db.
I have a model named `ExternalAppointment` that I want to map data to.
here's my controller :

```
    [HttpPost("xml")]
    public async Task<ActionResult<Appointment>> XMLContent([FromBody] ExternalAppointment xmldata)
    {
        //stuff.
    }
```

here's my `startup.cs` :

```
        services.Configure<RequestLocalizationOptions>(options =>
        {
            //some code
            services.AddMvc()
            .AddXmlSerializerFormatters();
            //rest of code
        }
```

here's the xml I'm passing in postman:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<event>
   <business_owner_id>1</business_owner_id>
   <business_owner_name>Doctor's lab</business_owner_name>
   <business_owner_phone_number>44556699887</business_owner_phone_number>
   <customer_email>example@example.com</customer_email>
   <customer_phone_number>1122336655</customer_phone_number>
   <date_and_time>16/12/2021 20:45:00</date_and_time>
   <location>21 jump street</location>
   <service_name>PCR</service_name>
</event>
```

and I can't seem to get through to the request, I keep getting 405 response.
I tried adding `[consumes("application/xml")]` decorator before the controller but it did not help.

any ideas ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is  my demo with XElement,and it can work:

Startup:

```
 public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddControllersWithViews();
            services.AddMvc()
            .AddXmlSerializerFormatters();
        }
```

ApiController:

```
 [Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class ApiController : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpPost("xml")]
    public IActionResult XMLContent([FromBody] XElement xmldata)
    {
        return Ok();
        //stuff.
    }
}
```

postman(You need to make sure you use post request):
[image]

result:
[image]